# undefined method `is_admin?' for nil:NilClass :(

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, admin, activeadmin

I want to restrict the access to my pannel admin (gem active_admin) for admin only.

That's my code

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    def authenticate_admin!
        unless current_user.is_admin?
            flash[:error] = "Access denied"
            redirect_to root_path
        end
    end
```

and the problem is : **undefined method `is_admin?' for nil:NilClass**

there is a boolean admin (0 false, true 1) in my DB

I've to define my is_admin?, but i try and he  is never found. So where do i have to do that ?

Thx for your help

Comment: make sure current_user is not nil before calling is_admin? on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your error message. nil doesn't have the method 'is_admin?'. This means that your current user variable isn't being set. You need to redirect users who are not logged-in to a screen where they can do so. Then direct them either through this `authenticate_admin!` function either first to redirect all user who are admin to the `/admin` path or simply push all users to your home page allowing them to click an admin link.

Comment: I've been set my current_user in the ApplicationController

Answer (score 0):

It could be that current_user is being set correctly, but this method is being called when there is no logged in user.

You should use this method in conjunction with another filter which requires the user to be logged in, ie which requires current_user to be defined.  This is typically called `require_user`

Eg, in your application controller (so it gets inherited by all controllers)

```
before_filter :require_user

protected
def require_user
  unless current_user
    redirect_to "/" and return
  end
end
```

You then make exceptions for the non-logged-in actions, with `skip_before_filter`.

Now, you can add authenticate_admin! as a before filter in your admin controller: it will only ever by called when require_user has already been passed, so it should be safe.

Comment: If i do that i'm in an infinite loop, so i think it's cause my current_user is nill. 
I've to fix that first i think

Comment: The loop is happening because your home page is triggering the "require_user" filter too.  That would be an example of where you would use a `skip_before_filter`.  eg in whichever controller handles the home page - `skip_before_filter :require_user, :only => [:index]`.  (this assumes that the index action handles the "/" url)

Comment: In addition to my last comment, let me say that this is an **example** of how someone **might** use `require_user` and `authenticate_admin!`.  Obviously i don't know your requirements so you'll need to make your own mind up.

Answer (score 0):

Add try: `<% if current_user.try(:is_admin?) %>`

Answer (score -1):

Try simply add `before_action :authenticate_user!` (if your user called 'user') before `:authentificate_admin!` method. After this change your app will redirect non-logged users to login form first and only after that will ask your user 'is he admin?'.